# remove jQuery in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, meteor

I am removing jquery getting value in React by using this.refs.element.value.

How can I remove jQuery in this and do it in React way?

```
var arr = [];
$(".mail-checkbox:checked").closest("tr").each(function() {
    arr.push( this.id );
});
```

Comment: Need to see more code. A lot more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building app with React you should not touch DOM yourself. Manipulate objects in React component and add some flag if object is checked or not. Update state and React will update DOM in best possible way.

Remember, that React uses virtual dom and you are editing with this script real dom, it will make React's dom with real dom out of sync and your app will work a lot harder to get back in sync than it should.

Comment: can you send a sample  with adding some flag if object is checked or not